# listener c# like java

Tags: c#, listener

I have field string in struct, 
and i want learn real-time changed this field.

```
struct example {
public string ex;
}

examp = new example();<BR>
examp.ex = "test";

////// then program work and eamp.ex = "bing";
```

I need method

```
on_ex_changed() 
{
    if examp.ex changed then ..... 
}
```

online and simple plz

Comment: You may take a look on how events work in .Net: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx

Comment: See http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-snippet-tutorial-custom-event-handlers

Answer (score 4):

You can put an event at the setter as follows.
The event will be fired every time the setter is called.

```
public class MyObj
{
    private RectangleF mRectangle;

    public event EventHandler RectangleChanged;

    public RectangleF Rectangle
    {
        get
        {
            return mRectangle;
        }

        set
        {
            mRectangle = value;
            OnRectangleChanged();
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnRectangleChanged()
    {
        if (RectangleChanged != null)
        {
            RectangleChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: basvas: it changes when the property setter is called, so you DO know.

Comment: where write than Rectangle changed?
protected virtual void OnRectangleChanged()
    {
        if (RectangleChanged != null)
        {
            RectangleChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            Console.WriteLine("ee"); // dont work
        }
    }