# Any ideas on how to make the UI react when a property on a class is changed?

Tags: c#, winforms, class, properties

For example, I have this small class:

```
public class SednaTreeViewItem
{
    public string ValueMember { get; set; }
    public string DisplayMember { get; set; }

    public SednaTreeViewItem(string valueMember, string displayMember)
    {
        ValueMember = valueMember;
        DisplayMember = displayMember;
    }
}
```

Then I use it in a user control as such:

```
/// <summary>
/// SednaTreeViewItem that is currently selected in the SednaTreeView.
/// </summary>
public SednaTreeViewItem SelectedItem
{
    get 
    {
        if (ultraTree.SelectedNodes.Count > 0)
        {
            var node = ultraTree.SelectedNodes[0];
            return treeNodes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ValueMember == node.Key);
        }
        else
            return null;                
    }

    set 
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            ultraTree.ActiveNode = ultraTree.Nodes[value.ValueMember];
            ultraTree.Select();
        }                
    }
}
```

Then in the actual form that uses this user control, I'd like to capture whenever the .Text is changed in a textbox, to have that text changed as well in the user control, which is a treeview.

```
private void txtInvestor_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    treeViewInvestors.SelectedItem.DisplayMember = txtInvestor.Text;
}
```

The problem is that when I changed the value of .DisplayMember, nothing fires to let the treeview know when to update the display text of the node.

Do you have any suggestions on how to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Control Binding like:

```
this.txtInvestor.DataBindings.Add("Text", this, "SelectedItem", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

Comment: +1. @Sergio, you'll also want to make SednaTreeViewItem implement INotifyPropertyChanged. Read up on [data binding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454959/winforms-databinding).

Comment: Phenomenal, the INotifyPropertyChanged interface fit like a glove. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

You should create an event for your class property and then register that event inside your UI class.

The accepted answer in the following link should help you out:

[C# : Creating Events for a Class on GET/SET properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302827/c-creating-events-for-a-class-on-get-set-properties)